# Blocking all app's exits on Andorid 12, Java

Tags: java, android, android-12

I used in android 10 to use the OnUserLeaveHint() to block every way out of my app except the home button which retrieved the app after 5 seconds, but it seems it doesn't work anymore on Android 12.

Is there any other way to block app's all exits even if it exits and comes back after 5 seconds on the home button it is fine.

I tried pinning the app, but it isn't such a good of solution because the user can just unpin the app and exit it.

Any idea or code would help,
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a device that is supposed to be used for a single purpose, either use kiosk mode or have the app serve be registered as the launcher.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, thanks for the help. Is there any other way that replaces onUserleaveHint on Android 12? If not and I become the phone main Home button operator, how do I block the exit from the apps menu button and exit threw notifications which onUserLeaveHint blocks